# Different layer color on mobile

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

Is there an option to set a different color on PC and a different one on mobile?
For example: I have a text where the font in PC is gray, but in mobile it is white.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to do this. Here is 2 of them and maybe there are more.

1) Wordpress has a function *wp_is_mobile()*

wp_is_mobile() returns 'true' in case the device is a smart phone, tablet etc.
So you can create conditions for mobile display with php.

For Example:
in a template (for that the css classes have to be defined of course ;) )

```
<h1 class="<?php ( wp_is_mobile() ) ? 'color-white' : 'color-grey' ?>">
   ... display title ...
</h1>
```

2) You can use **media queries** in your css file(s) to change properties on devices with smaller screen resolutions.
For example: 
This would set the color of h1 to white for screens smaller than 768.
And on any other displays the h1 color would be grey (as set by the general rule).

```
h1 { color: grey; }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    h1 {
          color: #fff;
    }           
}
```

This is very general since you didn't say where the change would/should be.
I hope it helps.
EDIT: I just noticed afterwards that the topic is also tagged with the revolution slider. So I'm not sure if this is of any help to that specific plugin. Just let me know and I'll delete it if its not relevant.

Cheers